# How to keep the newest rows only in a WITH RECURSIVE statement effectively?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, mysql-8.0

I have some initial rows in a table. I would like to modify them with a recursive call. In my example code this function is a simple multiplication by two, and I would like to execute it 5 times:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n,v) AS
(

  -- initial values
  SELECT 0,2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 0,3

  UNION ALL

  -- generator
  SELECT n + 1, v * 2 FROM cte WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT v FROM cte where n = 5;
```

It works, but my problem is that it only filters out the unneeded values at the end of the query. If I start with much more rows, it can degrade performance, because I have way more rows in the memory as I should. Is it possible to keep the newest values only in each iteration?

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/6761

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you know that this code is possible in MySQL 8.0 so you might acted to fast by removing the MySQL tag.

Comment: Why was this question tagged with both the MySQL and SQLite?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Because I am looking for a solution, which works in both

Comment: "Because I am looking for a solution, which works in both" -> Provide table structure with example data on sqlfiddle.com  And post expected output based on that example data as ascii table data..  i've added the mysql 8.0 tag because MySQL 8.0 is the only MySQL version which allowes Common table expressions (WITH AS clause)

Comment: I updated the question with an sqlfiddle link. It provides the expected output, I am just looking for a more optimal solution

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite you can use [OFFSET clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html)

> - The OFFSET clause, if it is present and has a positive value N,
>     prevents the first N rows from being added to the recursive table. The
>     first N rows are still processed by the recursive-select — they just
>     are not added to the recursive table. Rows are not counted toward
>     fulfilling the LIMIT until all OFFSET rows have been skipped.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/6804

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n,v) AS
(

  -- initial values
  SELECT 0,2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 0,3

  UNION ALL

  -- generator
  SELECT n + 1, v * 2 FROM cte WHERE n < 5 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 10

)
SELECT * FROM cte

| n |  v |
|---|----|
| 5 | 64 |
| 5 | 96 |
```

In the example above the offset is calculated as the number of initial rows in the initial select (2 rows) times the number of iterations (5) => 2*5=10

---

By the way, in this concrete example the better solution would be calculating simple `X * 2^5` 
(X mltipled by power of 2 to 5) instead of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, the CTE is implemented as a coroutine (as shown by the [EXPLAIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) output), so only the current row is kept in memory, and performance will not degrade due to memory usage.

MySQL [does not allow LIMIT in the recursive SELECT part](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). If I interpret [WL#3634](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3634) correctly, the implementation in version 8.0 always completely materializes recursive CTEs.

So in SQLite, you do not need to do anything, and in MySQL, you cannot do anything.